# Sails is not being installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sails.js

I have tried installing Sails by using all the possible ways I found on internet but I am not able to start sails.
Every time I use "sails lift" , it says "sails not installed".
Is there any hardware issue or version issue ?

Answer (score 1):

To have the command `sails` available, you have to install it with `npm install -g sails`, and you can use the generator to create a skeleton project with `sails new myProject` if it doesn't work, you should be able to lift sails with `node app.js`

Answer (score 0):

try installing sails locally.

ie; try this command `npm install sails` instead of global installation `npm install -g sails`

Answer (score 0):

If you trying sails lift on windows 8 or older one then it's not working in windows local CMD you have to lift it on in node servers CMD,
Don't worry about node CMD it by default installed when you install node.